# php sqlsrv - field not updating

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

i want to update two fields from a table called Leave Request but when i click on the submit button.

```
 <?php 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request] dbo.[KPMG$Leave Request].supAprrove_date=?,dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].supAprrove=? WHERE     dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].id=?');
$stmt->execute(array($adate, $approve, $id));

$adate = $_POST['supAprrove_date'];
 $approve =$_POST['supAprrove'];
$id = $_POST['lid'];
 //$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="pending_leave.php">
  <label>
  <select name="supAprrove" id="supAprrove">
    <option value="1">Approve</option>
    <option value="2">Reject</option>
  </select>
  </label>
  <input name="supAprrove_date" type="hidden" id="supAprrove_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lid" id="lid"  value="<?php echo $data['id'];  ?>"/>
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: That is how the database tables are names

Comment: What is the error you get? It seems that you don't handle any errors from `sqlsrv`. Please check the usage of [`sqlsrv_errors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296200(v=sql.105).aspx). Also, `SET` is missing just after `UPDATE dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one way to create a SQL UPDATE statement is

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
column2 = expression2,
...
[WHERE conditions];
```

Example:

```
UPDATE employees
SET last_name = 'Johnson'
WHERE employee_id = 10;
```

You are using prepared statements so replace the 'Johnson' part with "?" and you are done.

For error handling you can use:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

The part `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is the key to throw exceptions.

More on PDO error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: I replace the name 'Johson' with a post variable like $_POST['name'] but it doesnt work

Comment: That is fine, but I think your query is wrong so try to change the query. And I would change the table name so there are no spaces between the words and also it is not best practice.